# How does first strike work with multiple blockers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have an [Edgar Markov](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEdgar%20Markov%5d) that is currently attacking as a 10/10. My opponent assigns four creatures with a total of 20 power to block it. Does Edgar kill all of those blockers or does he only kill two of them?

Comment: I was trying to improve your question but had to give up halfway into that run-on sentence because I couldn't figure out what youwere trying to say. Please make a better effort to ask your question in a comprehensible way.

Comment: @Hackworth I edited the title based on what I think was being asked if that helps

Comment: But yes that is the question

Comment: I was going to write up a summary of the attack phase in the hopes that the answer would be in there somewhere for you, but with an attitude like that I suddenly feel less inclined to help. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ (And I still don't actually know what the question is.)

Comment: Well for one he was rude first so he deserved it so don’t worry

Comment: The question is that will edgar be felt damage by no first strike creatures

Comment: After dealing damage to other creatures

Comment: You should consider editing your question so that it is more clear to what you are asking.

Comment: Well I can’t really because realistically I’m trying to ask a weird question

Comment: So what I’m asking is that say some blocks Edgar for 20 damage obviously he will kil the two that equal ten but will he Kill the other two creatures that will kill him

Comment: I am also having trouble following what you are asking. You mention the number 20 in your comment but not the question and it's not exactly clear how that fits in, and I think you're missing a word or two in "block with four of the that equals more than Edgar’s attack"

Comment: So Edgar is a 10/10 and the number of blockers someone is dealing Edgar is 20 damage and four blockers so I’m asking does Edgar kill all of those blockers or does he only kill two of them

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how first strike interacts with multiple blockers so it doesn't really matter what the attacking creature is but rather what the power and toughness of the attacking and all the defending creatures is.

Comment: In your case it would depend on the toughness of the defending creatures and if the attacker is able to kill them. For example if one defender was 20/20 they would kill your creature but if it was 20/5 it would not.

Comment: No I’m asking if more that one creature blocks Edgar and the power equals 20 combined

Comment: Or even better way to explain it is after dealing ten damage to two creatures can Edgar still attack other creatures that are blocking him

Comment: I have edited your question to be a bit clearer. Does that still match what you were trying to ask?

Comment: Yes I also have a question about overwhelming splendor

Answer (score 4):

The outcome of a battle like this depends on the exact power and toughness of each creature involved.

If Edgar is blocked by four 5/5 creatures, then Edgar will 5 first strike damage to each of two of those creatures, which will die. Then the other two creatures will deal 5 damage each to Edgar, and Edgar will die.

If instead Edgar is blocked by two 4/6 creatures and two 6/4 creatures, then Edgar's controller can choose to deal 4 damage to each of the 6/4 creatures and the other 2 damage to one of the other creatures. In that case, both 6/4 creatures will die and the surviving creatures will only deal a total of 8 damage to Edgar, so Edgar will survive.

In general, the important thing to look at is not just the total power and toughness of the creatures involved, but also how it is distributed among the creatures. The basic question is whether the creature with first strike can kill enough of the other creatures that the remaining blockers don't have enough power.

Comment: I also have a question about overwhelming splendor

Answer (score 1):

First strike happens first.  Edgar kills as many blockers as he can.  Those blockers are gone.

Next, the blockers that are left damage Edgar.  Edgar doesn't get to damage them again, he already got his chance.  Maybe Edgar survives, maybe he doesn't, but he doesn't kill any more blockers.

(If Edgar had "double strike", then he would be able to attack again in the second part, and kill more blockers.)